# Flutter : Pressing back button closes two screens

Tags: android, ios, flutter, navigation

I have navigate from Dashboard to Some Screen called 'A'. In that screen, I have shown a listing using ListView Builder. In that, clicking on item in ListView navigate to another Screen called "B". When I press back button in that Screen "B" its navigate to Dashboard. But it has to navigate to Screen "A". Please help me to resolve this issue.

In Dashboard, I have use below code to Navigate to Screen "A",

```
  _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, Item item) {
    switch(item.name)
    {
      
      case "Disputes":
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Disputes()));
        break;
        
    }
  }
}
```

In Screen "A", I have use below code to Navigate to Screen "B",

```
 Card(
                                                child: ListTile(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    Navigator.push(
                                                        context,
                                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                                SubmitDisputes(disputesId: disputeResList[index].id.toString())));
                                                  },
                                                  trailing: Icon(
                                                      Icons.remove_red_eye),
                                               
                                              ));
                                        }),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

When I press back button in Screen "B", its navigate to Dashboard. But I need to navigate to "A" as per the backstacks.

Please help me!

Comment: Seems all good, did you tried to stop the app and restart it again (not hot reload) ? and are you calling ```.pop()``` somewhere in the code ?

Comment: Nope Not. I add ``` .pop() ``` only in app bar action. Its happening when I pressed android system back button or IOS swipe back. I restarted and created a release apk too. But not working

Comment: Can you please post all the source code for dashboard , Lease and SubmitDisputes ?

Comment: @ikerfah I edited the post with source code. Kindly look into that

Comment: I need to see your main.dart too please

Comment: I added main.dart

Comment: I added HomePage too. Hope I show all the code. Kindly help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: Could please use ```rootNavigator: true``` as second parameter whenever you are using Navigator ? ```Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).push(...)```

Comment: Where I have to add this. In Homepage or Dispute Page?

Comment: Everywhere :D , Glad it worked. i'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as discussed in the comments. using `Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).push(...)` fixed the issue.
But why did you faced this issue at first ? because you have multiple `MaterialApp` in your app. you have to keep only the one in `main.dart` as root widget. so you have two options:

1. Use only one `MaterialApp` as root widget and call `Navigator.of(context).push(...)`
2. Have multiple `MaterialApp` and use `Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).push(...)`

If you need my advice, use 1.